# Is there any online SharePoint development environment where can perform POC?

Tags: ms-office, sharepoint-online

Its a small requirement to modify existing functionality at our client. But need to perform the POC for the task. Is there any online SharePoint development environment where can perform POC, so that no need to set up SharePoint locally for this small task ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can sign-up for the Office 365 Developer Program which will send you a link for a 1-year free trial of an Office 365 Developer Subscription which includes a SharePoint Online Site. Click the link (https://profile.microsoft.com/RegSysProfileCenter/wizardnp.aspx?wizid=14b845d0-938c-45af-b061-f798fbb4d170&lcid=1033) to sign-up on http://dev.office.com